# How to avoid API clients during server side rendering and defer them to the client, in Angular Universal?

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have a fairly trivial Angular component that serves as the routing component of the homepage route of an Angular module. I am converting this project to Angular Universal, to take advantage of server-side rendering. The component does something very basic: lists data retrieved from a paginated API.

I am trying to achieve the following effect:

- Render the component with its basic template and business logic
- Make the first API call inside the ngOnInit() method of the component, not on the Server Side but ONLY on the Client Side.

My initial attempt was:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(PLATFORM_ID)) {
      console.log('in the browser');
      // Load the first chunk of data only
      // within the browser (not on server side rendering)
      const page = 1;
      this.fetchNextPage(page);
    }
  }
```

This doesn't work. I get neither the console.log nor the `fetchNextPage()` method is called. If I remove the wrapping `if()`, the Server Side rendering successfully calls the `fetchNextPage()` method and calls the target API to get the first page of data, but I'd like to avoid the effect of `NodeJS -> calling the real backend API` on production. I would like to keep the standardized `Frontend -> calling the real backend API` which is valid without SSR as well. My goal of using SSR is to accomplish faster First Contentful Paint and SO. It's not to defer full API communication to be server-to-server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to leverage Angular's DI to give you the information you need as follows.

```
import { PLATFORM_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
  const isServer = !isPlatformBrowser(platformId);

  if (!isServer) {
      console.log('in the browser');
      // Load the first chunk of data only
      // within the browser (not on server side rendering)
      const page = 1;
      this.fetchNextPage(page);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The culprit here is Injecting the PLATFORM_ID using DI, not simply importing and using it! That's a subtle difference but makes all the difference.

Comment: Thank you for this. I needed this in my application to only render a ngx-masonry on the client as it does not appear to work on server side rendering.  I use the `<div *ngIf="!isServerRendering">` to decide whether to render the contents of the div or not